# Calling this->get/this->set methods versus directly accesing member variables in C++

Tags: c++

Suppose I have a class `Foo`, with a private variable `bar_` containing some state for `Foo`. If necessary, I may write public get/set methods for `bar_`. Naturally, I avoid this as much as possible to maintain encapsulation.

Assuming I have these get/set methods, whenever I have to access or modify `bar_` within a method belonging to `Foo`, I usually do it directly to `bar_`, instead of using the get/set methods, which I use for accessing `bar_` from outside the class. I have no justification other than concerns regarding the speed of directly accessing the variable versus calling the methods, but I suspect that if the get/set methods are defined inline (which they are) it shouldn't make a difference. Does it make a difference? Does `const`ness play a role in this?

So far I haven't had any problems with this, but I have a lingering feeling I am Doing It Wrong. Are there any compelling arguments for not doing it? Any guidelines regarding this?

Comment: Write clean code. Use get/set methods. Premature optimization is the root of all evil.

Comment: Why `this->setBar(this->getBar() + 1);` is cleaner than `++bar_;`?

Comment: @dimatura: you may want to explain how you got access to the private members of another class.

Comment: nobugz: He's not talking about another class -- he's talking about using get/set methods within the other methods of the same class.

Comment: @Drakosha - followed closely by premature generalization.

Comment: @nobugz: As Brooks says, I'm talking about variables that are in "this", ie "this->bar_" versus "this->get_bar()". Sorry if it was not clear.

@KennyTM: I often feel similarly, but I try to keep the methods as short as possible with this->bar() to get and this->bar(value) to get, similarly to the way FLTK does it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I have no justification other than concerns regarding the speed of directly accessing the variable versus calling the methods, but I suspect that if the get/set methods are defined inline (which they are) it shouldn't make a difference. Does it make a difference? Does constness play a role in this?

The inline keyword hardly plays a role in whether or not the compiler does any inlining. The use for the keyword in that regard is essentially deprecated. Modern compilers inline like crazy, and they know when to do it better tan any programmer does.

Any compiler worth dirt will say "Hm, call this function to get this member variable; hey I can just get the member variable!" You're worrying about nothing. This happens regardless of any inline keywords.

That said, I almost always use the member functions. If I change how a variable behaves when it's accessed, I now "automatically" apply that everywhere it's used. Clean code should be your goal, though, not a dogmatic "always skip functions" or not.

Anytime I just want a variable value, I use the corresponding member variable. (i.e, if I were writing `std::vector`, if I needed to check if the size was less than something, I'd say `size() < x`). But if it's cleaner to use the variable directly, do that instead, such as `mSize++`.

`const`-ness is irrelevant. If you're in a non-const function, you'll use the non-const version of your getter, same with const. Obviously, using the members directly maintains const-ness. There is no difference.

Comment: Yep, the keyword is *instrumentation*.

Comment: A large part of the benefit of using get/set functions comes from using them reliably rather than sometimes using them and sometimes not.  What benefit do you get from using `size() < x` rather than `mSize < x` if you can't rely on being able to change `size()` to some other representation without affecting other code?

Comment: "if I needed to check if the size was less than something, I'd say size() < x)" -- especially since `size()` might well be implemented as `mEnd - mBegin`. That's a pretty good illustration of why something which is a getter in your *current* implementation might not be a getter (or have a corresponding member variable) in some *future* implementation. "This is the getter/setter for the private member Blah" is a bad way to describe an interface: it mentions an implementation detail. I support your avoidance of it and Brooks's statement that if you're going to avoid it, avoid it always :-)

Answer (score 14):

I know it is close to herecy, but I *hate* get/set methods. *Loathe* them. Almost never write them.

Generally, a class should either provide much more high-level operations than directly and simply reading and modifying internal state variables, or it should get out of the way and act like the `struct` it is.

Even if I were to write one, I would almost never use it *inside* the class. The whole point of them is that you can change the internal representation of thing without affecting a client. Inside the class, it is the internal representation you care about! **If you are tempted to do a lot of operations on the class using its own interface inside the class, you probably have a second class in there fighting to get out.**

Comment: I often myself torn between writing a full-blown Class versus a POD struct, but that may be matter for another question :)

Comment: I think you make a good point.  Too many people seem to think object-oriented programming is writing a getter and a setter for each of your member variables.  The correct thing to do is to make a high-level interface, which may include getters and setters for certain properties of that interface.

Comment: For internal work, I'm rather fond of "pseudoPODs" (structs with constructors).

Comment: I agree here - if you're using a lot of get/set methods you aren't really hiding the implementation details.

Comment: I wish I could +1 YOU instead of your comment.

So true.

Comment: Agree. The get/set pair have its place, but is much overused in the C++ world, not to mention that it goes to insane limits in the Java world. Even Bjarne Stroustrup wrote about that:

http://www.artima.com/intv/goldilocks3.html

Answer (score 2):

It's better to use the `get` and `set` methods: It's cleaner, upholds DRY principles better (only do validation once), and allows subclasses to override the methods and see consistent behavior on all changes to the variable.

Comment: Yes, the subclassing must be taken into account. As a rule I don't use protected variables, only private, so get/set would probably be preferable in this case. I feel that if I allow derived classes to directly access variable members of the base class things may get messy quickly. In general I do not use inheritance very much other than for abstract base classes.

Comment: `protected` variable scope tends to be a bit of a mess regardless, and using `get` and `set` in your internal methods means that child classes can be certain any validation they do in their overriding `get` and `set` will also be upheld.

Answer (score 1):

This is a matter of opinion, and a matter of judgement, but in general the interior of your `Foo` methods are within the encapsulation you're trying to maintain, and so it is entirely reasonable for them to access `bar_` directly.  They are all in the same location, and so if you change the interior representation of your class to remove `bar_`, you can easily find all of the uses to change as well.

There are justifications for using get/set functions internally in large classes, especially where `bar_` is something that's not a key piece of the class's implementation design and could conceivably be changed without affecting the rest of it much.  However, in many cases if you are changing the internal representation in such a way that `bar_` no longer exists and its corresponding `get_bar()` is computed, you will almost certainly want to revisit the internal usage to determine whether you want to refactor it so that it doesn't do that computation or does it differently.

With that said, speed is not a justification for not doing it -- but the comprehensibility cost of too many layers of encapsulation *are*; a forty-line class should not be complicated with additional internal encapsulation unless it's one of the cases where the encapsulation actually simplifies the code.

Edit: Also, ehdv raises an important issue that I missed: If you anticipate derived classes that override this piece of the internal representation, using get/set functions can make that overriding easier to do consistently.  So that can be another factor in the decision.

Answer (score 1):

get/set should only be necessary when there is some sort of invariant, precondition or postcondition that must be upheld by the class. If the modification of the value doesn't have a 'ripple effect' throughout the rest of the class then the user should be able to modify it directly. However if changing the value will cause something else to happen (e.g., changing a cache size might cause cached items to be purged) then get/set is appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

If your compiler does any inlining at all, it will be able to inline get and set methods defined and used within a given class.  `const` has no bearing on this, and the `inline` directive doesn't make much difference either.

I generally prefer to use my `get()` and `set()` methods even from within the class definition, when I can.  You get all the same benefits that you get by using them outside the class definition, and there is no speed penalty.

Answer (score 0):

There is no rule that fits every situation in my opinion. Sometimes, it is better to write these private set/get functions, sometimes it is not.

For example, if all what get/set functions do is this:

```
void set(int n)
{
   member_n = n;
}
int get_n() const
{
  return member_n;
}
```

Then, there is no need actually for these functions!

In other situations, where you need to normalize a value for example, you could write those get/set functions. e.g. to normalize an angle:

```
void setAngle(int angle)
{
  member_angle = angle%two_PI;
}
```

Comment: There's no need for the functions now.  I've had good experiences with getter/setter methods when I had to put hooks into the accessors.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use get/set function. 
Because I found that it is very hard to debug if use member variable directly.
Especially when you have a big class and there are a lot functions access bar_.